# User not found on cloud code call? Why?

Tags: parse-platform

I want to check if the cloud code request came from an actual user and then return data for that user only.

Here is my code. It passes the `!currentUser` test most of the time, but fails frequently even though I know there is a user making the request. Any ideas?

CODE:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getData", function(request, response) {
    var currentUser = request.user;
    if(!currentUser) {
        response.error("Failure: No user found on getData function");
        return;
    }
}
```

> ERROR: Failed with: Failure: No user found on getData function

Could this be due to ACLS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic seems entirely valid, I would suggest just before your `response.error()` call that you do a `console.log(request);` so you can look at the log and see more detail.

It could be that your calling code is making a request before the login has completed in the background (race condition), or that requests are being made after a user logs out.